# Is there a way to statically compile libscip?

Tags: scip

I have to build a MAPF Solver that is based on SCIP with CPLEX and I want to compile it statically, so that I don't need to install the set of libraries in the experimentation cluster. For this, I need to compile libscip statically, is there any way for doing this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried to modify the link.txt the CMake generates so that the linking is done statically, against static libraries, but this doesn't work. I also took a look to the CMakeList.txt but don't fully understand how the whole compilation workflow can be modified in order to generate a static library.

Comment: Have you tried `cmake SHARED=off`? This is how it should work

Comment: @Leon Thank you very much. I found that option in a CMakeList file I didn't check before (the compilation of the whole project depends on three of them). Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use cmake for achieving this.